# Защита от несанкционированного распространения QR кода с номером виртуальной карты лояльности из личного кабинета веб сервиса

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сайт

Возможно злоупотребление. Участник программы лояльности из Личного кабинета веб сервиса может сделать скриншот и отправить его третьим лицам.

Два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Запрет на скриншот
2. Условно короткий скрипт с символом, который есть в qr-коде в веб режиме, но не на скриншоте.

Comment: Во дурь-то... или в правилах получения такого QR владельцу запрещено делать скриншот **для своих нужд**? Да в пень тогда идёт такой QR..

Comment: Есть куча способов скопировать QR-код и без скриншота

Comment: Вам клиент бесплатно второго приводит, а вы его хотите как-то демотивировать? Такая себе модель ..

Answer (score -1):

Ну вот допустим в приложении КБ реализована следующая система:

1. QR код нельзя скринить.
2. QR код регенерируется каждые 30 секунд.
   Это позволяет избегать передачи QR-а третьим лицам